# Combinatorics - Choosing Seats

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are $20$ seats in a row. We have four identical boxes that are to be placed on these seats. However , it is known that no two consecutive seats can have boxes placed on them.

It is known that the $20^{th}$ seat has a box on it. In how many ways can the rest of the boxes be placed on the seats ?

My thoughts at the moment : It's about choosing $3$ chairs from the remaining $18$(effectively, since the $19^{th}$ chair cannot be chosen) that leaves us with $18$ chairs for the first box, $16$ for the next and $13$ for the next.

So that should leave us with $18 \times 16 \times 13$ boxes.

Edit: There are four boxes in total

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: The problem boils down to arranging 3 identical boxes on first 18 seats. For that, I think it will be easier to subtract the number of cases that are not allowed from the number of all possible cases.

Comment: Cases not allowed: 2 boxes together. For that group 2 boxes together and 2 seats together. Now see the total number of arrangements. Similarly do it for 3 boxes together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

**Method 1:**  As you observed, since there is a box in the 20th seat, we must place three boxes in the first $18$ seats, which can be done in $\binom{18}{3}$ ways.  From these, we must subtract those arrangements in which two or more boxes are placed in consecutive seats.  Since the pair of consecutive seats containing boxes must begin with one of the first $17$ seats, there are $17$ ways to place two boxes in consecutive seats and $16$ ways to place the remaining box among the first $18$ seats.  Thus, there are $17 \cdot 16$ ways to place the boxes so that at least two are consecutive.  However, subtracting $17 \cdot 16$ from $\binom{18}{3}$ removes each placement of the boxes in three consecutive seats twice, once when we count the two leftmost boxes and once when we count the two rightmost boxes.  Since there are $16$ ways to place three boxes in consecutive seats among the first $18$ seats, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways we can place the three remaining boxes in the first $18$ seats so that no two consecutive boxes contain a seat is 
$$\binom{18}{3} - 17 \cdot 16 + 16 = 560$$

**Method 2:**  Alternatively, let $x_1$ denote the number of empty seats to the left of the first box, $x_2$ denote the number of empty seats between the first and second boxes, $x_3$ denote the number of empty seats between the second and third boxes, and $x_4$ denote the number of empty seats to the right of the third box among the first $18$ seats.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 18 - 3 = 15$$
The requirement that no two boxes be placed in empty seats means $x_2, x_3 \geq 1$.  Let $y_2 = x_2 - 1$; let $y_3 = x_3 - 1$.  Then
\begin{align*}
x_1 + y_2 + 1 + y_3 + 1 + x_4 & = 15\\
x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + x_4 & = 13
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  The number of solutions of the equation is the number of ways we can insert three addition signs in a row of $13$ ones since three of the sixteen symbols (three addition signs and thirteen ones) must be addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{13 + 3}{3} = \binom{16}{3} = 560$$

Answer (score 3):

Any admissible configuration can be realized in the following way: Put $16$ empty seats in a row, with space between them. Choose three of these seats, put a box on them, and insert an additional empty seat immediately to the right of each chosen seat. Finally put a  seat with a box on it at the right end of the row. The total number of possible choices is ${16\choose 3}=560$.

Answer (score 1):

*Abridged after OP's clarification re* **total** *of 4 boxes*

A simple way is:

Remove  3 chairs from the unoccupied ones, and place boxes.

16 chairs (plus last occupied chair) are now left with 16 possible places ( _ ) where the 3 chairs removed can be pushed in, as shown below.

_c_c_c_c_c_c_c_c_ . . . . _c_c_c$\mathcal C$

$$\text{Thus answer} = {16\choose3} = 560 $$

Comment: Note that since the final seat is occupied, the seat next to it must be empty.  Hence, for four boxes (including the one in the last seat), there are $15$ remaining empty seats.  Consequently, there are only $16$ gaps to fill.  See my answers.

Comment: Since the last seat is occupied by a chair, you have $19$ chairs left.  You fill three of them with boxes, leaving $16$ chairs left.  You cannot place a chair with a box after the last emtpy chair since you would then have two consecutive chairs with boxes in them.  Thus, you have $16$ gaps in which you place a chair (before each of the $16$ empty chairs).

Comment: But you *can* place *before* the first empty chair.

Comment: That is true, but you cannot place after the $16$th empty chair since that would leave you with two consecutive chairs filled with boxes (namely, the last two places).

Comment: Oops, fenecepost error amended, thanks (+1)!